# How do I use IFormatProvider with ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, iformatprovider

The [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) interface allows me to create a class which does custom formatting of objects as strings and can be used with e.g. [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx).

However, there doesn't seem to be a simple way of using it with ASP.Net. For example, if I have a [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) I can create a [`BoundColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundcolumn.aspx) and use its `DataFormatString` to say how to format it, but I can't see any way to tell it to use my `IFormatProvider` implementation. `BoundColumn` seems to be limited to the default format strings.

The best solution I've found so far is to create my own class extending [`DataGridColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.aspx) which essentially duplicates the functionality of `BoundColumn`.

Is there a better way of doing it?